# Does creating a volatile class guarantee volatile class variables

Tags: java, singleton, volatile

Suppose the following singleton:

```
public class Test{
    private static volatile Test test = null;
    private static int test_int = 0;
    private static String test_string = "test";

    public int getInt(){
       return test_int;
    }

    public String getString(){
        return test_string;
    }

    private static Test getInstance(){
         if(test == null){
             synchronized(Test.class){
                if(test == null)
                    test = new Test();
             }
         }
    }
```

By declaring the singleton instance Test to be volatile are test_int and test_string also considered to be volatile or must they be declared as such? I want to think that by making the class itself Volatile then everything under that class would be volatile as well ... however I am not sure about this. Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, they aren't considered to be volatile. *Only* the `test` variable is volatile. After the value of `test` has been obtained (via `getInstance`) its volatility is irrelevant to the rest of the client's behaviour.

Personally I would consider using `AtomicInteger` and `AtomicReference` instead of `volatile`, to be honest. I don't know about anyone else, but I find volatile behaviour hard to reason about reliably.

Note that your probably don't want your `test_int` and `test_string` variables to be static...

Comment: +1: Agree that you should use a wrapper like AtomicInteger, AtomicLong or AtomicReference to handle safe operations. Only quibble is that you can only have volatile fields rather than local variables. ;)

Comment: how do we use `AtomicInteger` and `AtomicReference` in above example.Culd you edit and show it with a example

Comment: @Deepak: You simply make a final AtomicInteger (or whatever) variable, and then call the methods on the object to mutate the wrapped value atomically.